# how to make mesh mask an image

Tags: mesh, texturing, shaders, masking

I'll try to explain this as best possible. I'm trying to make a mesh mask an image like [the galaxy skin from fortnite](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jj0n7mGNWBM). how can I do this? I want the image to be only visible where the mesh is as you see in the skin

[here is a sample of the scene im working on](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13R3UTFJvVQ5DoiBLr2CIgXsXFGZSCUTn/view?usp=sharing). im trying to get the jacket to act with the image in the image editor as the galaxy skin acts with the galaxy image

all textures should be packed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are referring to the small stars in the body, you can do that using the *Window* or *Camera* output from Texture Coordinate node as input in your texture:

[image: Material nodes]

Result (using *Window* as input):

[image: Window coordinates texture result]